# Match words starting with capitals in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I have a string

```
 $str="NassarWellerGomez-GarciaSanchez-RenedoLoeches-SanchezGomez-GarciaMunoz-FerrerasSanchez-RenedoChiaoHakkarainenWernerValkamaHarounPlett";
```

I want to match words starting with capitals only like: 
Nassar
Weller
Gomez-Garcia etc

```
I used this : 

preg_match('/[A-Z][a-z]+/', $str,$match);
```

But its not working, help me out here please!

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Z][a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)*/', $str, $match);
var_dump($match[0]);
```

Comment: @BarryChapman Thanks, Fixed that. Also now matches `Foo-Bar-Baz` as a single name (any number of hyphenates allowed).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = preg_split('/[A-Z]/', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
var_dump($result);
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it will work, or at least point you in the right direction.

It does not work for the hyphenated names. For that, I believe you would need to use a (positive or negative) lookbehind, but I don't know enough to explain that off the top of my head. You'll have to look it up, but at least now you know what to look for.

---

Looking at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html as a quick reference, it looks like perhaps this would be the regex with the negative lookbehind you need:

```
'/(?<!-)[A-Z]/'
```

This basically means "match any capital letter *not* followed by a hyphen."

Comment: preg_split('/[A-Z].+/', $sno, 1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
This is working somewhat